# Unable to debug linux using eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I am trying to debug Linux using eclipse, after compiling the Linux kernel.
    I created a new project, now in run->debug configurations I gave path to vmlinux.
    gave TCP port and clicked on DEBUG.
    I got below error

```
"/home/linux-kernel/vmlinux": 
not in executable format: File format not recognized TCP port and clicked on debug.
```

Please point me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Take a look: http://issaris.blogspot.hu/2007/12/download-linux-kernel-sourcecode-from.html

Comment: I too followed the same link, thank you

Comment: Then you *could have mentioned it* in the post, and told us where you are stuck.

Comment: After doing necessary steps mentioned in the above link. i run run->debug configurations to get debug perspective. this is failing giving below error                                                                               "/home/linux-kernel/vmlinux": 
not in executable format: File format not recognized TCP port and clicked on debug.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel isn't an executable program. It takes over the whole computer. So you need to run the kernel on a different PC or on a PC emulator like [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page).

Here is a blog post which gives detailed instructions how to set everything up: [Debugging the Linux kernel using Eclipse/CDT and Qemu](http://issaris.blogspot.hu/2007/12/download-linux-kernel-sourcecode-from.html)

The error which you get suggests that you didn't configure remote debugging correctly. Instead of connecting to the running qemu, Eclipse tries to start the Linux kernel like a normal program. See here how to configure the Launch Configuration for remote debugging:

> Click on the "Debugger" tab, and in the "Debugger" listbox select the "gdbserver Debugger".
>   Next, modify the "Stop on startup at:" to "start_kernel".
>   Below this, you'll notice a frame named "Debugger Options";
>   click the "Connection" tab in this frame and modify the "Type" to "TCP" and the "Port number" to 1234.
>   Continue by clicking the "Debug" button.

If that doesn't work, make sure that qemu actually uses port `1234`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am running Linux on qemu, gave qemu-system-i386 -s -S -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage

Comment: See my edits; make sure the debug settings are correct